# .focusout() Not Working After .append() is Called and Used

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble trying to figure out why `.focusout()` is not being called after I use an `.append()` method. I have a button that adds another row of `input` to a table.

Now within that table, I check to see if the user is focusing out of an input. It works when it originally starts with one row, but after I click the button to `.append()` a new row to the `tbody`, it just poops.

I've tried both `.focusout()` and `.on("focusout")` and neither have been successful.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addRow").click(function () {
        $("tbody").append("<tr><td><input type='text' /></td><td>World</td></tr>");
    });
//    $("tbody input").focusout(function () {
//        alert("Focus Out");
//    });

    $("tbody input").on("focusout", function() {
        alert("Focusing out");
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addRow").click(function() {
    $("tbody").append("<tr><td><input type='text' /></td><td>World</td></tr>");
  });
  //    $("tbody input").focusout(function () {
  //        alert("Focus Out");
  //    });

  $("tbody input").on("focusout", function() {
    alert("Focusing out");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="addRow">Add Row</button>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" />
      </td>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="detector"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
$("tbody").on("focusout", "input", function() {
    alert("Focusing out");
});
```

Note that the "input" is moved to the second argument of `on`, this way it can apply to all future `input`s on `tbody` instead of just the one that exists when it's first called. I recommend you read the [jQuery.on docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)